# SQL Server TDE Vs SQL Server Database Backups

Tags: sql-server-2014, backup, transparent-data-encryption

Can anyone please help me understand below case:

Kindly advise on below case:

SQL Server is on 2014 SP2 GDR version

I read Compression and TDE does not go hand in hand .

**I have 2 PRD Environments:**

The table structures between server 1 and Server 2 are same.

- With DB Size around 400 GB in Server 1 with FileStream Enabled.
  FileStream content sized around 300 GB.
- With DB Size around 687 GB in Server 2 with FileStream Enabled.
  FileStream content sized around 600 GB

Currently the above Databases are with TDE Enabled.

**When I backed up below are the details when they are NOT on TDE:**

With DB Size around 400 GB in Server 1 took around 51 Minutes

With DB Size around 687 GB in Server 2 took around 108 Minutes

**When I backed up below are the details when they are WITH TDE:**

With DB Size around 400 GB in Server 1 took around 57 Minutes

With DB Size around 687 GB in Server 2 took around 207 Minutes

**My Observations**

In Server 1 with same specifications as Server 2 , time taken is 51 Minutes (Pre TDE) --> 57 Minutes after TDE Enabled

In Server 2 with same specifications as Server 1 , time taken is 108 Minutes (Pre TDE )--> 207 Minutes after TDE Enabled

**My Question**
Why is that difference when compared to time taken is almost doubled in Server 2 but Server 1 it is only 7 Minutes .

**NOTE**: Also , my Databases are with TDE + EFS (Encrypting File System) when backed up.

Kindly advise , as Compression and TDE does not go hand in hand . What is the reason why in Server 2 the time taken is DOUBLE , where as in Server 1 it is only 7 Minutes after TDE enabled.

Regards

Comment: Hi @JohnEisbrener , thanks for your response . Please see I updated my question. Thanks again

Comment: What Service pack/CU  you are running on 2014 ? Also, the timings are based on local backups or network backups ?

Comment: @Kin , currently I am on SQL Server 2014 SP2 GDR . Also , can you please help me if applying EFS increases Database timing and size ? Updated my question.

Comment: SQL server is unaware of EFS. So if EFS is slowing down, then definately the timing increases. Out of curiosity, why you have both EFS and TDE ? both will protect data at rest. So just choose 1.

Comment: Hi @Kin , Thanks for the response. Can you kindly elaborate little bit what does " SQL Server is unaware of EFS Means ?" . We have got Global rule out for our company that all our data should be protected by encryption. Structured data by TDE and Unstructured by EFS. So I need to work on both. Kindly share your thoughts on TDE , EFS versus Database Backups. Thank you

Comment: what I meant is that EFS is external to sql server. SQL server has no knowledge of how EFS does encryption. Can you exclude sql server related files mdf, ldf, trn, bak etc from EFS and see if that improves the timings ?

Comment: Thank you. Without EFS the time is reduced almost similar to pre TDE Timing.

Comment: there you have your answer.

Comment: @Kin, you should actually answer the question.  I'd gladly upvote it, and frankly I suspect this would be useful for others coming across this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments so far -

SQL server has no knowledge of how EFS does encryption. Turning off EFS - the timing is reduced almost similar to pre-TDE timing (confirmed by OP).

This means that EFS is slowing down the backups.

Remember that both EFS and TDE will protect data at rest. So, for sql servers, you should have a global policy to exclude sql server filesystem from EFS.